# can't get mac address while targetSdkVersion is 31

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mac-address

I get mac address in my app. when targetSdkVersion is 29 everything is correct, but when update targetSdkVersion to 31, I can not get mac address.

```
private fun getMacAddress(): String =
    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces().toList()
        .firstOrNull { it.name.equals("wlan0", ignoreCase = true) }?.let {
            it.hardwareAddress?.let { macBytes ->
                StringBuilder().apply {
                    for (b in macBytes) {
                        append(String.format("%02X:", b))
                    }
                    if (isNotEmpty()) {
                        deleteCharAt(lastIndex)
                    }
                }
            }?.toString() ?: run {
                "00:00:00:00:00:00"
            }
        } ?: "00:00:00:00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't.

According to [Android Developers - MAC address availability changes in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#mac-11-plus), they blocked the access to the MAC address if you target Android 11:

> In addition, non-privileged apps can't access the device’s MAC address; only network interfaces with an IP address are visible. This impacts the `getifaddrs()` and `NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()` methods, as well as sending `RTM_GETLINK` Netlink messages.

Also, from [NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface#getHardwareAddress()):

> For example, this method will generally return null when called by non-system apps having `targetSdkVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R.`

Answer (score 1):

You can't mac address in >= 31 SDK version
but you can uniquely identify your device using android_id

import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

```
private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```